# hibernate says table does not exist but it is creating the table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am developing a Spring app and I am using JPA with MariaDB for my databases. When the app starts it first throws some exceptions about not existing tables but it creates them. The app does not terminate after errors.

**Am I doing some thing wrong?**

**update:**

when I change

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

hibernate does not throw an exception any more.

**why?**

Logs summery:

```
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table roles_privileges drop foreign key FK5yjwxw2gvfyu76j3rgqwo685u" via JDBC Statement
...

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=105) Table 'users.roles_privileges' doesn't exist
...

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'users.roles_privileges' doesn't exist
...
2019-10-29 18:13:00.866  WARN 821 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table roles_privileges drop foreign key FK9h2vewsqh8luhfq71xokh4who" via JDBC Statement
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=105) Table 'users.roles_privileges' doesn't exist
```

User Entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class User implements UserDetails {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;

        @Email
        private String email;

        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String username;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String password;


        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
                name = "users_roles",
                joinColumns        = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "username"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "name"))
        private Collection<Role> roles;
...
    }
```

Role Entity:

```
@Entity
    public class Role {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;

        @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String name;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
        private Collection<User> users;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "roles_privileges",
        joinColumns        = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",      referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        )
        private Collection<Privilege> privileges;
...
    }
```

Privilege Entity:

```
@Entity
    public class Privilege {

        @Id
        private long id;

        @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String name;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
        private Collection<Role> roles;
....
    }
```

application.properties

```
#User datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/users
spring.datasource.username=user01
spring.datasource.password=user01pass

#`hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Comment: Hi @mehrd97d, so when you use "update", it only checks the mappings for Entity if they match: columns, types, keys, table names, etc. And it throws an exception only if some mapping it is wrong/missing. For "create-drop" it will first try to drop what you current have in the DB and try to create again, if you see the exception it is trying to alter table "roles_privileges" inside the schema users, maybe in your current db, this table 'roles_privileges' has a different owner/schema?

Comment: what do you mean by "... table 'roles_privileges' has a different owner/schema"? my DB does not have any tables, Spring create them when it starts.

Comment: i think you should change privileges column name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably not doing anything wrong.

When you use Hibernate's hbm2ddl auto with `create` or `create-drop`, Hibernate will try to create your database schema on startup.

You can turn on the `show-sql` property in your `application.properties` to see the generated SQL queries:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The queries might look something like this:

```
alter table `your_table` drop foreign key `FK...`
drop table if exists `your_table`
create table `your_table` (...)
alter table `your_table` add constraint `UK...` unique (`name`)
alter table `your_table` add constraint `FK...` foreign key (`foreign_id`) references `other_table` (`id`)
```

First Hibernate drops foreign key constraints, then drops the table, then creates the table, then adds constraints to it.

The error happens on the first query, when trying to drop a foreign key and the table doesn't exist yet. Nothing bad happens, you can ignore the error, the other queries will work and the table will be created correctly.

As far as I know, MySQL and MariaDB don't support something like a "drop foreign key if table exists" which would help to suppress the error.